# FIlter chain cycling issue - More than 100 threads work in back?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, jcifs

I have a weird case with my filters. I want to catch exceptions thrown from JCIFS Ntlm Http filter. Filter chain starts from my custom filter and I have surrounded chain.doFilter() part with try-catch block to be able to redirect response if any exception occurs. Here's code for web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>NTLM_FILTER_CHAIN_START_POINT</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filters.JcifsNtlmWrapperFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>NTLM_FILTER_CHAIN_START_POINT</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ntlm/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>NTLM_HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_FILTER</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filters.JcifsNtlmFilterImpl</filter-class>
        <!-- init params goes here -->
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>NTLM_HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_FILTER</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ntlm/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

JcifsNtlmWrapperFilter.java:

```
public class JcifsNtlmWrapperFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        try{
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("--------------- Catching Exception ------------");
            session.setAttribute("error", "NTLMFailedToAuthenticate");
            response.sendRedirect("/");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

And inside JcifsNtlmFilterImpl.java I'm just throwing an exception (its just for testing):

```
public void doFilter( ServletRequest request,
                          ServletResponse response,
                          FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication ntlm;

        System.out.println("--------------- NTLM Filtering ------------");
        if(1==1){
            System.out.println("--------------- Throwing Exception ------------");
            throw new IOException();
        }


        if ((ntlm = negotiate( req, resp, false )) == null) {
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter( new NtlmHttpServletRequest( req, ntlm ), response );
    }
```

Everything works as expected. User doesn't see any error messages thrown inside NTLM filter (but sees plain auth login page instead), but when I look inside glassfish logs then i see more than 100 Threads actively going through this filter cycle (a small copy-paste from logs):

```
[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.892+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=109;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|USER IP:127.0.0.1|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.909+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=108;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- NTLM Filtering ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.910+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=108;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Throwing Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.910+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=108;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Catching Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.927+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=110;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|USER IP:127.0.0.1|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.942+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=111;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- NTLM Filtering ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.942+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=111;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Throwing Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.942+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=111;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Catching Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.959+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=107;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|USER IP:127.0.0.1|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.978+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=109;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- NTLM Filtering ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.978+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=109;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Throwing Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:02.978+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=109;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Catching Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.004+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=108;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|USER IP:127.0.0.1|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.019+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=110;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- NTLM Filtering ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.019+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=110;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Throwing Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.019+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=110;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Catching Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.034+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=111;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|USER IP:127.0.0.1|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.051+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=107;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- NTLM Filtering ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.051+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=107;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Throwing Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.052+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=107;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Catching Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.067+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=109;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|USER IP:127.0.0.1|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.081+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=108;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- NTLM Filtering ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.082+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=108;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Throwing Exception ------------|#]

[#|2014-05-26T14:16:03.082+0500|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=108;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|--------------- Catching Exception ------------|#]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but maybe

```
response.sendRedirect("/");
```

Is sending you to your welcome page, that happens to be something triggering again the filter chain, rinse and repeat...  Have you tried to redirect to some specific resource outside the `/ntlm/*` pattern?  For example redirect to http://www.google.com and then see if that gives the same result in your log.

Comment: I was controlling if session has error key inside it. No problem should be there, but I have also tested it with http://www.google.com redirecting. But again more than 100 threads are busy with filter cycle. Maybe calling sendRedirect forwards request again to the next filter in the chain?

Comment: If you redirect your response outside your application, then you are sure that your application will have treated only 1 request... I am not sure now what is the problem :S

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return when catch some exception and not to call left filter.

you may need to call the following code from the ContainerRequestContext class:
`requestContext.abortWith(*,*)`

may be you need to check the related method in Filter class.